# Strong Hausdorff Space

Tags: general-topology

Consider a topological space $(X,\mathscr{T})$ such that for all compact $K$ and $x\in X\setminus K$ there exist open, disjoint $U,V$ such that $x\in U$ and $K\subseteq V$. I now want to show that for all compact sets $K,L$ there exist open, disjoint $U,V$ such that $L\subseteq V$ and $K\subseteq U$.

The first thing that came to mind is that for all $x \in L$ it follows that $x \in X\setminus K$, because $K$ and $L$ are disjoint. So one could find open, disjoint sets $U_x,V_x$ for every $x \in L$ such that $x \in U_x$ and $K \subset V_x$. So we would have:
$$L \subset \bigcup_{x \in L} U_x \in \mathscr{T} \text{ and } K\subseteq \bigcap_{x \in L} V_x$$
where
$$\left(\bigcup_{x \in L} U_x \right)\cap \left(\bigcap_{x \in L} V_x\right)=\emptyset$$
These seemed like good candidates for the final two open, disjoint sets I was looking for, but $\bigcap_{x \in L} V_x$ of course does not need to be open as $L$ could have infinite cardinality.

Must the intersection in this case be open and is there a way to show this? Or do you know of completely different proofs?
Some hints would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use the compactness of L.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks!If I have a finite cover of $L$ I only need finitely many of the sets covering $K$, hence their intersection is open!

Comment: Every Hausdorff space has this property.

Comment: Yeah, thats the point of the question :D

Answer (score 1):

The compactness of $L$ allows you to reduce the cover to finitely many $U_x$ and then the corresponding intersection will be open.

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to contradict the first. You cannot in general separate compact K from any disjoint L. (You can separate any K and disjoint closed L iff the space is regular.)

Comment: No, the assumption on X is just equivalent to Hausdorff. If any compact subset K can be separated from any disjoint L then the space is discrete (as you can separate {x} and X - {x}).